# Snowflake merge object / json

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

is there any way how to merge 2 objects in snowflake? I found https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/object_insert.html, but that only sets/updates one key at a time. I want to merge 2 objects (something like `Object.assign()` in js).
Also tried to find workaround by converting to array, concatenating and construction object from that array, but did not manage to make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Snowflake does not have a built-in function like that, but it's trivial to do using, well, `Object.assign()` inside Snowflake's [JavaScript UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js.html) :)

```
create or replace function my_object_assign(o1 VARIANT, o2 VARIANT) 
returns VARIANT 
language javascript 
as 'return Object.assign(O1, O2);';

select my_object_assign(parse_json('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'), parse_json('{"c":4, "d":5}')) as res;
-----------+
    RES    |
-----------+
 {         |
   "a": 1, |
   "b": 2, |
   "c": 4, |
   "d": 5  |
 }         |
-----------+
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks a lot! Hope it is performant enough though :)

Comment: well, it won't be as fast as a native function would be, that's true :( But hopefully it's fast enough!

Comment: This UDF will fail if `O1` is `NULL` -- but the solution is very simple; just add an empty object as the first parameter: `return Object.assign({}, O1, O2); `