# Joining two JSON objects in Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What's up,

I have two JSON objects, generated from the same Snowflake table (Table 1 here).
I want to join/merge them on their "_id" field, in order to produce this nested json kind of structure.

1. How can I do this? I tried aliasing them and using `SELECT * from dc JOIN rs ON rs.:_id = dc:_id` but I'm hitting invalid identifier error, or "unexpected keyword ON" errors.
2. Is there an easier way to accomplish this merge without doing two separate json OBJECT CONSTRUCT queries?

I've included the JSON samples below

```
{ "_id": 786433, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HL" }
{ "_id": 786434, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HN" }
{ "_id": 786435, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HP" }
{ "_id": 786436, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HR" }
{ "_id": 786437, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HS" }
```

Generated from a table

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    '_id', h."ID",
    'rmpostcode', "rmpostcode"
)
FROM TABLE1
```

And another

```
{ "_id": 524323, "coords": [ { "eastings": 265099, "northings": 666879 } ] }
{ "_id": 524381, "coords": [ { "eastings": 265787, "northings": 668537 } ] }
{ "_id": 524447, "coords": [ { "eastings": 265024, "northings": 668238 } ] }
{ "_id": 524496, "coords": [ { "eastings": 268534, "northings": 665428 } ] }
{ "_id": 524785, "coords": [ { "eastings": 260938, "northings": 664166 } ] }
```

Generated using

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    '_id', h."ID",
    'coords', array_agg(object_construct(
                        'northings', h."northings",
                        'eastings', h."eastings"))
)
FROM TABLE1
group by "ID"
```

---

EDIT: Attempting the answer suggested by @Felipe Hoffa still doesn't work. code below:

```
with dc AS
(
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    '_id', h."ID",
    'coords', array_agg(object_construct(
                        'northings', h."northings",
                        'eastings', h."eastings"))
)
FROM "V_TABLES_09092020"."DEV"."v31av8oct20hyperoptic" h
group by "ID"
),
rs AS
(SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    '_id', h."ID",
    'rmpostcode', "rmpostcode"
)
FROM "V_TABLES_09092020"."DEV"."v31av8oct20hyperoptic" h
)

SELECT my_object_assign(dc, rs)
FROM dc 
JOIN rs 
ON rs:"_id" = dc:"_id";
```

gives me a `SQL compilation error: error line 23 at position 3 invalid identifier 'RS'`

I'm also struggling to create temporary tables in this way:

```
create or replace temp table dc AS 
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    '_id', h."ID",
    'coords', array_agg(object_construct(
                        'northings', h."northings",
                        'eastings', h."eastings"))
)
FROM "V_TABLES_09092020"."DEV"."v31av8oct20hyperoptic" h
group by "ID"
```

but I get

```
SQL compilation error: Missing column specification
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are generating two different JSON objects from the same table and then attempting to join them using SQL? Why can't you just select the result you want directly from TABLE1? It might help if you could show the schema of TABLE1 and some sample data. At the moment it seems like you are constructing JSON objects for no reason.

Comment: Yes I think it can be done with one JSON - the object I want is ` '{ "_id": 786433, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HL" ,"coords": [ { "eastings": 265099, "northings": 666879 } ]}`

If that makes sense. ID, rmpostcode, eastings and northings are all fields in TABLE1

Comment: What I'm struggling with is the GROUP BY when I'm wrapping the coords together like this - I have to group by ID, and there are many other fields I'd like merged in

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without any information about the data and table you are querying. e.g. what is the relationship between "_id", "rmpostcode" and eastings/northings? Is there a 1:1 relationship between id and postcode? are there multiple sets of coords per postcode? The answer to your question depends on the table and data and you haven't given much information about that, so if you could expand on that then I will try and give you the solution.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified - everything is 1-1 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to fix the query: You need to add quotes to `"_id"`:

```sql
SELECT * 
from dc 
JOIN rs 
ON rs:"_id" = dc:"_id";
```

[image]

Setup:

```sql
create or replace temp table dc as
select parse_json(value) dc
from table(split_to_table('{ "_id": 786433, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HL" }
{ "_id": 786434, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HN" }
{ "_id": 786435, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HP" }
{ "_id": 786436, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HR" }
{ "_id": 786437, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HS" }', '\n'))
;

create or replace temp table rs as
select parse_json(value) rs
from table(split_to_table('{ "_id": 786433, "coords": [ { "eastings": 265099, "northings": 666879 } ] }
{ "_id": 786434, "coords": [ { "eastings": 265787, "northings": 668537 } ] }
{ "_id": 524447, "coords": [ { "eastings": 265024, "northings": 668238 } ] }
{ "_id": 524496, "coords": [ { "eastings": 268534, "northings": 665428 } ] }
{ "_id": 524785, "coords": [ { "eastings": 260938, "northings": 664166 } ] }', '\n'))
;
```

--

Update: If you then want to combine both objects, you could solve this with a simple [assign() JS UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105286/snowflake-merge-object-json):

```sql
create or replace function my_object_assign(o1 VARIANT, o2 VARIANT) 
returns VARIANT 
language javascript 
as 'return Object.assign(O1, O2);';

SELECT my_object_assign(dc, rs)
FROM dc 
JOIN rs 
ON rs:"_id" = dc:"_id";
```

[image]

Comment: The output I wanted was actually ``` '{ "_id": 786433, "rmpostcode": "LL65 1HL" ,"coords": [ { "eastings": 265099, "northings": 666879 } ]}```

How would I do this?

Comment: Check the updated answer, added how to combine objects. And please make sure to include the desired output in future questions :)

Comment: Thanks - I want to accept your answer, but it still hasn't help me get to the bottom of my problem. I've added the code in my question in an edit - could you suggest what migth be the error?

Comment: You need to give names to your `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT()` -- add an `AS rs` to the first one, and a `AS dc` to the second one.

Comment: with `with dc AS
(
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(...` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228323/discussion-between-christopher-turnbull-and-felipe-hoffa).

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on your comments I think your situation is that you have a table defined similar to this:

```
create or replace temporary table public.test1 (
  "ID" numeric(38,0),
  "rmpostcode" varchar,
  "eastings" numeric(38,0),
  "northings" numeric(38,0)
);
```

In this table you have a 1:1 relationship between ID and rmpostcode and each eastings/northings combination. Something like this:

```
insert into public.test1 ("ID", "rmpostcode", "eastings", "northings")
values  (1111, 'ABC123', 256789, 887345), 
        (2222, 'LH9ZXQ', 678443, 921009),
        (9876, 'PZ12RR', 876234, 237862),
        (4567, 'W113LM', 234233, 123244)
;
```

To extract this tabular data into a JSON object where the eastings/northings values are in an array, you are correctly trying to use the OBJECT_CONSTRUCT and ARRAY_AGG functions but based on your example code I think your issue is not defining the GROUP BY expression correctly.

This code should produce a JSON object like the one you are describing:

```
select object_construct(
    '_id', "ID", 
    'rmpostcode', "rmpostcode", 
    'coords', array_agg(object_construct(
                        'northings', "northings",
                        'eastings', "eastings")
                       )
     ) 
from public.test1 
group by "ID", "rmpostcode"
```

Result:

```
{    "_id": 9876,    "coords": [      {        "eastings": 876234,        "northings": 237862      }    ],    "rmpostcode": "PZ12RR"  }
{    "_id": 4567,    "coords": [      {        "eastings": 234233,        "northings": 123244      }    ],    "rmpostcode": "W113LM"  }
{    "_id": 1111,    "coords": [      {        "eastings": 256789,        "northings": 887345      }    ],    "rmpostcode": "ABC123"  }
{    "_id": 2222,    "coords": [      {        "eastings": 678443,        "northings": 921009      }    ],    "rmpostcode": "LH9ZXQ"  }
```